# Chamar arquivo PHP em form HMTL

Tags: html, php-7

Desejo chamar um arquivo .PHP, porém não consigo.

Possuo esse script:

========

```
    <html>
<header>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</header>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>O que deseja fazer?</legend>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" onclick="javascript: location.href='pagina.php';" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

=========

Esse Script não funciona. O que faço errado?

Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende, se vc só quer redirecionar para a página no ato do click, vc deve criar a tag para link se não, o ato for o cadastro e vc quiser enviar dados para trabalhar com eles no PHP, a opção do rafael augusto é válida.
Tag de link:

```
<a href="pagina.php">Cadastrar</a>
```

Comment: OK. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, espero ter ajudad. Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Coloque no form um `action="pagina.php"`

Exemplo `<form method="post" action="teste.php"></form>`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas, se permitir, teria alguma forma de eu fazer isso, sem usar o ACTION do form, mas usando o ONCLICK do botão?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Desejo chamar um arquivo .PHP, porém não consigo.

Possuo esse script:

========

    <html>
<header>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</header>
<body>
<form method="post" action="pagina.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>O que deseja fazer?</legend>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<form action="pagina.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    
    <input type="submit" value="Ir para Pagina">
 </form>
```

É so usar o action :D

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas, se permitir, teria alguma forma de eu fazer isso, sem usar o ACTION do form, mas usando o ONCLICK do botão?